# Encode my NFC tag with NDEF by manually writing the bytes?

Tags: byte, nfc, encode, mifare, ndef

I have a MIFARE Classic 1k, I used a reader to read everything on the card and would like to encode any data I write to it in NDEF so it can be read by a phone. I can only manually write the bytes atm and don't really know where to go from here. (I removed the data i wrote and replaced it with zeroes because it was sensitive)

Tried using different software but it seems like im the only one who wants such a weird thing done, here is the dump of the card. I do know the 16 sectors are separated by the KeyA ACs and KeyB (...FFFFF078069FFF...) Each sector being four blocks long ending in the keys, and all sector zero is used for is manufacturer info and UID.

Block 0: 77 57 DF D7 28 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69

Block 1: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 2: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 3: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF

Block 4: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 5: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 7: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF

Block 8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 9: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Block 11: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF

And so on until block 63...

Comment: When you say "read by a phone" you mean read using software you are going to write?

Comment: No Iphones and other phones can only read ndef cards, they already have readers and dont need software

Comment: Whats your question?